# How to use subsequent-sibling selector in React CSS modules

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, babel-plugin-react-css-modules

How would I write and call this CSS in React CSS Modules?

```
.is-invalid ~ .validationError {
    display: inline !important;
}
```

Calling `styles.validationError` does not work.

Comment: Yo'd better show a demo to us to explain a clear question.

Answer (score 0):

You are referring to [babel-plugin-react-css-modules](https://github.com/gajus/babel-plugin-react-css-modules) in the question tags, but don't provide any further context how you use it. This makes it hard to understand your exact problem, but I'll give it a shot anyway.

I assume you are trying to import a CSS file as a module like this:

```
import styles from "./styles.module.css"

const MyComponent = () => {
  return <div>
    <input className={styles['is-invalid']} />
    <div className={styles.validationError}>...</div>
  </div>
}
```

Your CSS will generate two locally scoped classes when imported as a CSS module. The code above works as expected when you use regular CSS modules, for example via a [Webpack loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader).

However, the Babel plugin that you use actually expects a different way of adding styles. Here is what you should do according to the [documentation](https://github.com/gajus/babel-plugin-react-css-modules#conventions):

```
// no need for named import here
import "./styles.module.css"

const MyComponent = () => {
  // note the different attribute: `styleName`
  //   - `styleName` uses a literal string
  //   - before, `className` used a variable from the imported `styles` module
  return <div styleName="validationError">...</div>
}
```

`babel-plugin-react-css-modules` will load the CSS at compile time and replace the `styleName` attributes with the scoped `className`s inline. The docs linked above explain this in further detail.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this by using global.

```
:global(.is-invalid)~.validationError {
    display: inline !important;
}
```

I can now call ${syles.validationError} and it works.

Answer (score -1):

```
return (
  <>
    <div className={styles['is-invalid']}>
    
    </div>
    {/* some Node or nothing, is-invalid and validationError are brothers. */}
    <div  className={styles.validationError}>123</div>
  </>
)
```

Comment: calling styles.validationError does not work

Comment: is-invalid and validationError are brothers.

Comment: Hey @YinPeng.Wei, thank you for your answer. Maybe you can improve your answer with an explanation or a working example using codepen or codesandbox?

Comment: OP's post is too simple to explain his question clearly, and he do not care about our answer. If you need, I will send a sandBox.